# i need to retrieve customer review for product using amzon api

Tags: amazon-web-services

By using C#, I want to get customer review on products from Amazon. I could not find any api,function, method, example by searching web.

To do this, is there some facilities in Amazon API? If yes, how can I do that. If not, how can I start?

Answer (score 0):

You need use [Amazon Marketplace Web Services](https://developer.amazonservices.com/). There are several other Web Service API available - you have a complete list from [developer.amazon.com](https://developer.amazon.com/).

**Amazon Marketplace Web Services - Info from their site**

> Amazon Marketplace Web Service (Amazon MWS) is an integrated Web
>   service API that helps Amazon sellers to programmatically exchange
>   data on listings, orders, payments, reports, and more. XML data
>   integration with Amazon enables higher levels of selling automation,
>   which helps sellers grow their business. By using Amazon MWS, sellers
>   can increase selling efficiency, reduce labor requirements, and
>   improve response time to customers.
>
> Amazon MWS supports seller API functions that are broader in scope and
>   functionality than any API functionality previously offered to sellers
>   by Amazon. With Amazon MWS, Amazon listing, order, and payment data
>   can be integrated into existing workflows so that selling on Amazon
>   fits seamlessly with sellers' current business practices.

Comment: i know very well about MWS but it's not provide customer review on product. You have another options